# How can I restrict the upload on Files based on Record Type?

Tags: trigger, related-list, files

I have a Contact Object with two record types (Client & Intake).

I am enabling the "Files" related list to both page layouts, however, I only want the Intake record type to have the "Upload Files" or "Add Files" capability. The Client record will only be able to View Files.

I want to have this feature though regardless of User Profiles. Is writing a Trigger the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is no issue in writing the trigger with your business logic and validating and throwing the error at before insert/before update.